# Dart - return string, not instance of the class

Tags: dart

I'm new to Flutter/programming and can't solve this, any help is appreciated.
Just trying to return the name of a day ie.  2 = Tue

```
String dayname = dayGetter(day).toString();

  dayGetter(int daynumber){
   var daynames = ['none','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
   return daynames[daynumber];
  }
```

This works fine, but I want to separate the function to its own file.

```
String dayname = NumberToDay(daynumber: day).toString();
```

.

```
 class NumberToDay {

      final int daynumber;
      NumberToDay({this.daynumber});

      var daynames = ['n/a','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'];

     test(){
       return daynames[daynumber];
      }
 }
```

But this returns:  Instance of 'NumberToDay' and I have no idea why or how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Your the question is more relative to dart than to flutter, I suggest you edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the class method call and instead calling the class's `toString()` method, which will indeed print its instance name. Just create an instance of your object and then call its method.

```
NumberToDay myObjectInstance = NumberToDay(daynumber: day);
String dayName = myObjectInstance.test();
print(dayName); // should print correctly
```

If you want a more immediate way, you can just call the method without keeping the object reference.

```
String dayName = NumberToDay(daynumber: day).test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Week days:
I saw that you have created a class and method to manage days of the week. 
There is something ready here that can help you a lot...

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/DateTime/weekday.html

Getting the 3 first letters of week day:

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/substring.html